# Question on Zorn's lemma

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Zorn's lemma states

> Suppose a partially ordered set $P$ has the property that every chain (i.e. totally ordered subset) has an upper bound in $P$. Then the set $P$ contains at least one maximal element.

Now, of course, the rationals $\mathbb{Q}$ satisfy the condition that every chain has an upper bound in $\mathbb{Q}$. But $\mathbb{Q}$ does not contain a maximal element, a contradiction.

Where is my line of reasoning going wrong?

Comment: $\mathbb Q$ is particularly badly chosen, because even bounded chains may not have an upper bound in $\mathbb Q$, like a chain of rationals converging towards $\sqrt 2$ from below.

Comment: dkuper: Bounded chains in $\mathbb Q$ do have an upper bound but may lack a *least* upper bound.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What is an upper bound of the chain $\mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathbb{Q}$?  (or $\mathbb{Q}$ itself, for that matter.)

Comment: Suppose $x, y \in \Bbb{Q}$.Take any rational y in 0 < x < 1 such that x < y.

Comment: @Josie: I am having trouble making heads or tails of your comment above.  But ask yourself this question: is there a rational number $q$ such that $n \leq q$ holds for _every_ integer $n$?

Comment: That wasn't readily obvious, thanks!